# OAuth callback with hash (#)

Tags: twitter, oauth

I use OAuth for Twitter authorization, the callback is

```
http://www.mysite.com/#/TwitterAuthCallBack
```

when I Twitter returns

```
http://www.mysite/?oauth_token=oauth_token&oauth_verifier=oauth_verifier#/TwitterAuthCallBack
```

however if the callback is

```
http://www.mysite.com/TwitterAuthCallBack
```

than works perfectly

```
http://www.mysite/TwitterAuthCallBack?oauth_token=oauth_token&oauth_verifier=oauth_verifier
```

But I need the first variant.

Thanks for answers